# What would be the hexadecimal representation of the largest memory address in a memory consisting of 4MB if each cell had a one-byte capacity?

Tags: byte, computer-science, bit, ram, memory-address

**What would be the hexadecimal representation of the largest memory address in a memory consisting of 4MB if each cell had a one-byte capacity?**

Since 4MB is equal to 4*1,000,000 Bytes, can I assume that there is 4,000,000 cells? Afterall, each cell can hold a maximum number 8-bits which means 255 variations. How can 255 variations be enough to represent 4,000,000 different values ?

I think there's a specific point that I've missed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Clearly the memory address is not limited to a single byte. You are just asked for the value of the largest memory address for that memory. If you want to store such addresses in the same memory, you could always store them across multiple cells (though that is not the question).

Comment: Lets say you have a limited memory of 4MB (4x1024x1024, it is not equal to 4000000 bytes), you need 22 bits to address this region. That makes your address region as 0x000000-0x3FFFFF. However, you need at least 3 bytes to keep a 22 bit value. Remember that CPU data word size and address size are different terms. Addresses can be represented with multiple words.